# Matplotlib - set Alpha and color dynamically

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I'm plotting a scatter plot from a Pandas dataframe in Matplotlib. Here is what the dataframe looks like:

```
       X  Y    R
0      1  945  1236.334519
0      1  950   212.809352
0      1  950   290.663847
0      1  961   158.156856
```

And here is how i'm plotting the Dataframe:

```
ax1.scatter(myDF.X, myDF.Y, s=20, c='red', marker='s', alpha=0.5)
```

My problem is that i want to change how the marker is plotted according to how high or low the value of `R` is.

Example: if `R` is higher than 1000 (as it is in the first row of my example), `color` should be yellow instead of red and `alpha` should be 0.8 instead of 0.5. If `R` is lower than 1000, `color` should be blue and `alpha` should be 0.4 and so on.

Is there any way to do that or can i only use different dataframe with different data? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a custom RGBA color array:

```
colors = [(1,1,0,0.8) if x>1000 else (1,0,0,0.4) for x in df.R]

plt.scatter(df.X,df.Y, c=colors)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This is a very good solution. What if i want to add more conditions than only 2? Can i just use a series of elif?

Comment: Try `np.select`. If that doesn't work, a series of `if...elif` isn't to bad.

Comment: Thank you a lot! How would it work with np.select? Give me 5 minutes and i'll accept your answer!

Comment: Your `R` column is string type. Change it to numeric with `pd.to_numeric` or `astype(float)`

Comment: Thank you! Can i do the same with alpha?

Comment: `alpha` is the last number in the tuple of 4, e.g. `(1,1,0,0,0.8)` means R=1, G=1, B=0, Alpha=0.8, or yellow with alpha=0.8.